# Bloomberg API NotFoundException encountered

Tags: java, bloomberg

I have a code that requests data from Bloomberg using Bloomberg API.
After I had fixed the external JARs needed and installed a new JDK (JDK 1.8), It ran without any problems. However, when I ran it again after I edited the company IDs whose securities I want to request from Bloomberg it displayed the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.bloomberglp.blpapi.NotFoundException: securityData not found in: HistoricalDataResponse
        at com.bloomberglp.blpapi.impl.aL.e(ElementImpl.java:3070)
        at com.bloomberglp.blpapi.impl.aL.d(ElementImpl.java:3045)
        at com.bloomberglp.blpapi.impl.aL.getElement(ElementImpl.java:558)
        at com.bloomberglp.blpapi.impl.h.getElement(MessageImpl.java:164)
        at bbg_upload.test1.processHistoricalStockDataResponse(test1.java:252)
        at bbg_upload.test1.handleResponseEvent(test1.java:221)
        at bbg_upload.test1.doo(test1.java:206)
        at bbg_upload.test1.main(test1.java:117)
```

I am still not very familiar with Bloomberg API. However, when I tried to run the same code on another PC, it ran without showing the above exceptions.

The code in line 252 is the following,
(specifically the line where "securityData" is)

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String available_date = dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date());

Element securityDataArray = msg.getElement("securityData");
String ticker = securityDataArray.getElementAsString("security");
String line = "";
String value = "";

Element fieldDataArray = securityDataArray.getElement("fieldData");
```

I've been googling why I'm getting this error. I think it's not in the implementation of Bloomberg API since it runs successfully on another PC. It might have to do with the environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already figured out the reason why it fails in `Element securityDataArray = msg.getElement("securityData");`

I added trying to check if the message has a responseError

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String available_date = dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date());

if(msg.hasElement("responseError")){
    System.out.println("responseError encountered! " + msg.getElement("responseError").getElement("message"));
}

Element securityDataArray = msg.getElement("securityData");
String ticker = securityDataArray.getElementAsString("security");
String line = "";
String value = "";

Element fieldDataArray = securityDataArray.getElement("fieldData");
```

It then, displayed the following.
(I replaced uuid, SN, sid, nid with x's for security purpose)

```
responseError encountered! message = uuid: xxxxxxxx, SN: xxxxxx, sid: xxxxxxx Monthly limit reached. [nid:xxx]
```

The bloomberg terminal on the problematic PC has reached its monthly limit, while the PC where I first reported where the code runs successfully hasn't yet. (It does not encounter responseError)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the locale that is setup on either machine, the date output by this line of code : `String available_date = dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date());` might not be the same for your machine and second machine you tried which is why I think the it works on one machine and not the other.

`Date` is a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch ( 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970).

t has no concept of format.

For example...

```
Date myDate = new Date();
System.out.println(myDate);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(myDate));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(myDate));
System.out.println(myDate);
```

Outputs...

> Wed Aug 28 16:20:39 EST
>
> 2013 08-28-2016 2013-08-28
>
> Wed Aug 28 16:20:39
> EST 2016

None of the formatting has changed the underlying Date value. This is the purpose of the DateFormatters

Try doing a tostring on the date and then use the formatter on that. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried doing the following
`String available_date = dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date().toString());`
but it gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`
format() method only operates on Date object and not string.

Also, I tried printing out the date in both PCs and it gives me the same format. i.e.
`new java.util.Date()` gives _Tue Aug 16 09:44:44 SGT 2016_
`dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date());` gives _20160816_
in both PCs